# sending a record type as parameter using dwscript

Tags: delphi, class, record, dwscript

Please consider this record:

```
Type 
  TStudent = record
    Name:String;
    Age: Integer;
    Class:String;
  end;
```

I have a class **TSchool** that has the following function:

```
function AddStudent(LStudent:TStudent):Boolean;
```

I want to use this class (**TSchool**) in the dwsunit, and this function too, but i can't figure out how to send the record type as parameter.
This is how far i've reached:

```
procedure TForm1.dwsUnitClassesTSchoolMethodsAddStudentEval(Info: TProgramInfo;
  ExtObject: TObject);
begin
  Info.ResultAsBoolean:=(ExtObject as TSchool).AddStudent(Info.Vars['LStudent'].Value);
end;
```

but this is not working, it keeps on giving me error about incompatible types.

I have also defined in the dwsunit a record TSchool, but this didn't work either.
Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: "I want to use this class in the dwsunit, and this function too" which class? or were you referring to the record?

Comment: what Delphi version are you using?

Comment: btw. you can use RTTI to expose TSchool to the script engine

Comment: I'm using Delphi 2010. how can i use RTTI? i added the RTTIConnector and connected it to my script, but didn't know how to write my code according to it, or what functions to use. I'm new to DWScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Delphi 2010 at my disposal now, but I do have Delphi XE(it *should* work in D2010 also), so here's what works for me, you can of course modify to fit your needs:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
   SysUtils
  ,Windows
  ,dwsComp
  ,dwsCompiler
  ,dwsExprs
  ,dwsCoreExprs
  ,dwsRTTIExposer
  ,Generics.Collections
  ;

//  required
{$RTTI EXPLICIT METHODS([vcPublic, vcPublished]) PROPERTIES([vcPublic, vcPublished])}
{M+}

type
  //  student definition
  TStudent = record
    Name: string;
    Age: Integer;
    AClass: string;
  end;

  //  student list, we use generics
  TStudentList = class(TList<TStudent>);

  //  school class
  TSchool = class(TObject)
  private
    FStudentList: TStudentList;
  published
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    procedure AddStudent(AStudent: TStudent);
    function GetStudentCount: Integer;
    function GetStudent(Index: Integer): TStudent;
  end;

{ TSchool }

procedure TSchool.AddStudent(AStudent: TStudent);
begin
  FStudentList.Add(AStudent);
end;

constructor TSchool.Create;
begin
  FStudentList := TStudentList.Create;
end;

function TSchool.GetStudentCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FStudentList.Count;
end;

function TSchool.GetStudent(Index: Integer): TStudent;
begin
  Result := FStudentList[ Index ];
end;

destructor TSchool.Destroy;
begin
  FStudentList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TestRecords;
var
  LScript: TDelphiWebScript;
  LUnit: TdwsUnit;
  LProg: IdwsProgram;
  LExec: IdwsProgramExecution;
begin
  LScript := TDelphiWebScript.Create(NIL);
  LUnit := TdwsUnit.Create(NIL);
  try
    LUnit.UnitName := 'MySuperDuperUnit';
    LUnit.Script := LScript;

    //  expose TStudent record to the script
    LUnit.ExposeRTTI(TypeInfo(TStudent));
    //  expose TSchool class to script
    LUnit.ExposeRTTI(TypeInfo(TSchool));
    //  compile a simple script
    LProg := LScript.Compile(
      'var LSchool := TSchool.Create;'#$D#$A +
      'var LStudent: TStudent;'#$D#$A +
      'var Index: Integer;'#$D#$A +
      'for Index := 0 to 10 do begin'#$D#$A +
        'LStudent.Name := Format(''Student #%d'', [Index]);'#$D#$A +
        'LStudent.Age := 10 + Index;'#$D#$A +
        'LStudent.AClass := ''a-4'';'#$D#$A +
        'LSchool.AddStudent( LStudent );'#$D#$A +
      'end;'#$D#$A +
      'PrintLn(Format(''There are %d students in school.'', [LSchool.GetStudentCount]));'#$D#$A +
      'LStudent := LSchool.GetStudent( 5 );'#$D#$A +
      'PrintLn(''6th student info:'');'#$D#$A +
      'PrintLn(Format(''Name: %s''#$D#$A''Age: %d''#$D#$A''AClass: %s'', [LStudent.Name, LStudent.Age, LStudent.Aclass]));'
    );

    if LProg.Msgs.HasErrors then begin
      Writeln(LProg.Msgs.AsInfo);
      Exit;
    end;

    try
      LExec := LProg.Execute;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        WriteLn(E.Message + #$D#$A + LExec.Msgs.AsInfo );
    end;
    Writeln(LExec.Result.ToString);
  finally
    LScript.Free;
  end;
end;

begin
  try
    Writeln('press enter to begin');
    Readln;
    TestRecords;;
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: sounds interesting, ill give it a try, and reply back, thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, Everything went fine, and worked properly. But may i ask an additional qeustion? Why if I had a dynamic array, i can't use the ExposeRTTI method (The Error is: **Cannot expose dynamic array of type: record**)... Thanks

Comment: please note that the dynamic array is of records (ex: **TClass: array of TStudent**)

Comment: @Zeina regarding "dynamic array of type", there is minimum support added for that, but only for simple types like integer, string, float and variant, anything else is left untested